# Applying CNN to Short-time Fourier transform?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, fft

So I have a code which returns a Short-Time Fourier Transform spectrum of a .wav file. I want to be able to take, say a millisecond of the spectrum, and train a CNN on it.

I'm not quite sure how I would implement that. I know how to format the image data to feed into the CNN, and how to train the network, but I'm lost on how to take the FFT-data and divide it into small time-frames.

The FFT Code(Sorry for ultra long code):

```py
rate, audio = wavfile.read('scale_a_lydian.wav')

audio = np.mean(audio, axis=1)

N = audio.shape[0]
L = N / rate

M = 1024

# Audio is 44.1 Khz, or ~44100 samples / second
# window function takes 1024 samples or 0.02 seconds of audio (1024 / 44100 = ~0.02 seconds)
# and shifts the window 100 over each time
# so there would end up being (total_samplesize - 1024)/(100) total steps done (or slices)

slices = util.view_as_windows(audio, window_shape=(M,), step=100) #slices overlap

win = np.hanning(M + 1)[:-1]
slices = slices * win #each slice is 1024 samples (0.02 seconds of audio)

slices = slices.T #transpose matrix -> make each column 1024 samples (ie. make each column one slice)


spectrum = np.fft.fft(slices, axis=0)[:M // 2 + 1:-1] #perform fft on each slice and then take the first half of each slice, and reverse

spectrum = np.abs(spectrum) #take absolute value of slices

# take SampleSize * Slices
# transpose into slices * samplesize
# Take the first row -> slice * samplesize
# transpose back to samplesize * slice (essentially get 0.01s of spectrum)

spectrum2 = spectrum.T
spectrum2 = spectrum2[:1]
spectrum2 = spectrum2.T
```

The following outputs an FFT spectrum:

```py
N = spectrum2.shape[0]
L = N / rate

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4.8, 2.4))

S = np.abs(spectrum2)
S = 20 * np.log10(S / np.max(S))

ax.imshow(S, origin='lower', cmap='viridis',
          extent=(0, L, 0, rate / 2 / 1000))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency [kHz]')
ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]');
plt.show()
```

(Feel free to correct any theoretical errors that I put in the comments)

So from what I understand, I have a numpy array (spectrum) with each column being a slice with 510 samples (Cut in half, because half of each FFT slice is redundant (useless?)), with each sample having the list of frequencies?

EDIT: So the above code theoretically outputs 0.01s of audio as a spectrum, which is exactly what I need. Is this true, or am I not thinking right?

Comment: show what you have come up with ... this is not a code writing service ... and yes independent thinking is encouraged and rewarded

Comment: That's why I'm asking for the thought process. My initial thought would be to take each column, and consider that to be a single "instance" of the .wav file. (Basically, take a matrix size (510,1) and use that for my CNN). The only issue I have with that is the slices overlap, so I would have a lot of redundant samples being used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CNN to Short-time Fourier Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293721/how-to-apply-cnn-to-short-time-fourier-transform)